# How to Explicitly Round to a Given Number of Significant Digits

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions, significant-figures

I have a given number: $N$, and I would like to explicitly round it to the nearest 2 significant digits

I have the following working equation that seems very redundant to me:
$$\begin{align*}
x &= \left\lfloor\log(N)\right\rfloor-1\\
y &= N 10^{-x}\\
\text{Answer} &=\left\lfloor y + (y \bmod 1)\right\rfloor 10^{x}
\end{align*}$$
I chose to use the $Floor$ operation here because I know that I can explicitly break down any floor function into $$\lfloor x\rfloor = x - (x\bmod1)$$

I know that calculating $x$ is probably necessary because I need to find the position of second most significant digit, but I can't help but feel that there is a much simpler way of performing the rounding as dropping down to a tens' digit and raising it back to it's proper position seems rather redundant to me.

Thank you in advance for all of the help

Comment: I am trying to simplify an equation that uses aggressive rounding so I need to expose the rounding function. What if N is a large number like 1150? I would like  1150 to round to 1200.

Comment: It is for programming, is there some bit hackery method of rounding? I'm trying to expose the function so I can simplify a much grander equation by grouping like terms, replacing multiple divisions by the same denominator with multiplications of 1/denominator, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, very limiting, I need it to run using VBA. But if there is some method of doing it using a more low level language such as C++ I would love to know!

Comment: I observe that VBA [has](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function) a `Round()` function.  Your method of decimal shifting so that there is exactly one digit left of the decimal mates well with that function.

Comment: Round functions are great, and I almost completely forgot about bit shifting to truncate! Unfortunately neither will work in this situation. You see I'm trying to simplify a loop that calculates a total by turning the loop into a single summation equation. If I can simplify the summation I should be able to create an equation that runs in constant time, but to do so I have to be able to mathematically represent the rounding functions so I can expand the summation that encapsulates it. Also $N$ needs to be capable of being any real number (integer or decimal).

Comment: Well, $log$ is a loop, internally :-)  [quite fast, tbh, running on the math proc]

Comment: That's fair :) but the loop I'm trying to simplify has at least 400 iterations complete with its own operations (albeit definitely less taxing than $log$), so I think in the long run $log_{10}$ will still be the cheaper alternative

Answer (score 1):

Take a number like $5.678758$. Then multiply it by $100$ to get $567.8758$. You can see that it places the two decimal places in the integer area now, so that only the ones place, which was the original number's hundredths place, will be affected by the round function, which is what happens when you round something to two decimal places.

The round function will make it so that when when the tenths place of our new number is $5$ or above $5$, the ones place of our number increases by $1$, otherwise, it doesn't change. This is exactly what we want, because we want a number like $5.687$ to round up to $5.69$, and a number like $5.683$ to round down to $5.68$. So, then use round() function on this number to get $568$.  Now divide by $100$ to get $5.68$.

So, in short you want to program a function like this for a number $x$: $f(x) = round(100x)/100$.